# What does "or you risk" means?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is the last paragraph extracted from the link http://www.livestrong.com/article/479103-is-eating-raw-spinach-good-for-you/

What does ***or you risk*** means? Does it mean that *if i wash ( at home) the "pre-washed" labelled spinach's i might get the risk of bacteria contamination from kitchen or hands, according to the report.*?

> Cooking spinach thoroughly is the most effective way to avoid food poisoning. But washing each leaf separately can lower health risks, making it relatively safe to eat raw, according to a 2009 report by ABC News. If the package of raw spinach you purchase is labeled “pre-washed,” “triple washed” or “ready-to-eat,” don’t wash the spinach, **or you risk** contaminating the spinach with bacteria from your kitchen or hands, according to the report. Also, don’t buy spinach if it is bruised or damaged.

NOTE: Please first respond whether my interpretation is correct or not.

Answer (score 6):

Your interpretation seems correct - but you do not *get* a risk, you *run* a risk. Which means the same as *you risk* something.

> Don't play with guns or you risk getting hurt.

Means "if you play with guns, you may get hurt".